# how to identify id attribute of input tag in all websites in Java?

Tags: java, html

Nowdays Each and every website have different id attribute of input tag.

For example:-

Facebook have `pass`as id for password field.

LinkedIn have `login-password`as id for password field.

My question is,Is there any way to identify these id for all website in java?

Comment: Why you need these? html is client side language why you want that in Java?

Comment: In my project I have a login automation task, for that I need id attribute of input tag but every website have different id.

Comment: So you could read complete html page (login page) source of any site and find / filter input tag  having id match with 'pass' or something common part using Regex and pick the id attribute of that input.

Comment: Ok and Thanks Nitin Dhomse.

Comment: maybe you could try to identify the `input`s with attribute `type="password"` and then get the value of their `id` attribute if you need it

Comment: Ok Nitin Dhomse